# hr in HTML breaks div:first-child?

Tags: css, html, css-selectors

I have a div with 2 floated divs inside. Above them there is a HR tag. I am trying to use the first-child as the divs should have a spacing between them. This doesn't work, however. The rule never gets applied. Seems like hr tag breaks it; if I remove the hr it works alright. Also :last-child works for alright, with or without hr. Anybody has some logical explanation for this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style>
        #outer {
            width: 600px;
        }
        #outer > div {
            float: left;
            width: 290px;
            background-color: #1982c8;
        }
        #outer > div:first-child {
            margin-right: 20px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="outer">
        <hr>
        <div>
            First inner.
        </div>
        <div>
            Second inner.
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BHT99/)

Comment: It's pretty simple really: `first-child` applies to the first child of an element. You are making the `hr` the first-child, which makes the  div the second child

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `<hr>` element is indeed the first child of its parent, not the `<div>`. Therefore, `:first-child` is not appropriate here.

If the browsers you target support CSS3, you can use [:first-of-type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3afirst-of-type) instead:

```css
#outer > div:first-of-type {
    margin-right: 20px;
}
```

Comment: I see, I guess I got this wrong since the beginning. Does this mean that when I select with the pseudo selector :first-child, the thing I want to select actually DOES have to be the first child of its parent? If there is some other element (different tag) above it, it won't select the element I have the first-child on? (like in this case div:first-child)

Comment: @Fygo, yes, `:first-child` only matches the element if it is the first child of its parent. `hr:first-child` would match the `<hr>`, and `div:first-child` cannot match the `<div>`.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
#outer > div:nth-of-type(1) {
            margin-right: 20px;
        }
```